# Excel formula converting tan to angle

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, trigonometry, degrees

I have an excel spreadsheet that computes the Tan of an angle in degrees.

I need a formula that will convert the cell `(Tan<)` to an angle in degrees.

**FYI:**

I can send excel spreadsheet if needed.

Comment: Some research would have told you that you are looking for the `ATAN` function.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=ATAN(A1)*180/PI()
```

.
.